# Reading in .csv file through pandas read_csv but only getting first two rows, any ideas why?

Tags: pandas, windows, csv, visual-studio-code, data-manipulation

I am trying to read in a .csv file through pandas read_csv but it is only reading in the first two rows without throwing any error messages. Here is what my code looks like:

```
for person in ppl:
    dt = pd.read_csv('..//netExpo//{}_netExpo.csv'.format(person)', encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
```

The csv should be 1762 by 1571 but the dt only has 2 by 1571. I have tried chunksize=1000 (then concat into dt), encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False, different delimiters, but nothing works. I also view the csv file in excel and it looks pretty correct to me.

Anyone has any ideas what the problem might be? I am using python on VScode on a windows computer.
A subset of the csv file looks like this in excel:

```
 0               1             2  
    
0  aa              bb            cc      
1  df              ed            gd     
2019-5-31   2018-08-10   2019-09-20
```

Starting from the third row it is all dates instead of strings as in the first two rows, also only the first two rows have row index 0, 1. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Please use the preview until you formatted your code properly.

Comment: Why do you look at a CSV file in Excel? Look at it in a good text editor instead. Excel might have done all kind of magic.

Comment: Show is the *text* of the first half-dozen or so lines of the CSV, and the code used to read it that returns only the first two rows.  This is called a [mcve].  When we can reproduce the problem, we can easily suggest a solution.

Comment: Can you try adding `skiprows=2` to your `pd.read_csv` call and let us know what happens? I think your idea about the change in the index might have some merit, and this could help illuminate.

Comment: @telianer I added skiprows, now it is not reading in any rows.. Any idea what I should do? Thanks!!

Comment: As @MarkTolonen said, is there any way you can provide us with sample of the top 20 rows or so in your CSV? This would likely make troubleshooting easier.